# How do I make an alert that I can dismiss forever in BootstrapVue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I'm looking to create a dismissable alert in BootstrapVue as described [here.](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/alert#dismissible-alerts) The alerts I've made based on the examples reappear when you refresh the page - I want to be able to make one that gets dismissed forever. This way, I can present an announcement to the user, but once they read and acknowledge it, they need not see it every time they revisit my page.

I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing that (I'm still learning Vue). Would a toggleable alert as described in the docs retain its state? Or is there a direct way to achieve what I need by saving the state of the alert (dismissed/not dismissed) in `localStorage` or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Yes as you said, `localStorage` is perfectly fine to use it for this case.

Just bare in mind, that `localStorage` is only stored in the current device that user is using. For example, if the user uses mobile and checks your announcement then the announcement will not be visible in mobile, but if user opens other device(laptop, etc..) then the announcement will pop up again.

In case you want always to know for all devices (for each user account) then this should be saved in a database and through an api endpoint to get this information and know when to show the announcement.

Add item in localstorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('YourItem', response.data)
```

You can fetch this using:

```
localStorage.getItem('YourItem')
```

To delete this from localStorage:

```
localStorage.removeItem('YourItem')
```

Comment: That’s perfectly fine for my case. Any chance you could show me how to implement localStorage with an example please?

Comment: Official doc: https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/client-side-storage.html

Comment: @Sidewinder I updated my comment on how to use the local storage.

Comment: thank you, I saw the documentation there but wasn’t able to wrap my head around connecting that to an alert. I’ll give it another try and mark your answer after.